# Align an image inside paragraph in HTML5

Tags: css, html

I used to just `align="left"` an `img` inside `p` tags before but `align` is not supported anymore in HTML5.

What's the recommended way of doing the code below in HTML5?

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" align="left">
  some long text
</p>
```

Comment: As you know, align attribute is no more supported in HTML5, so you will have to use CSS.

Comment: Yeah but I'm looking for the recommended way, so is it just `text-align:left;` ?

Comment: "not supported anymore in HTML5" — It was deprecated in 1998 … two decades ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
p img{
  float: left;
}
```

This rule will apply on all images under `<p>`

```css
p img{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
 <p>
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/30x30/?text=A"/>
        some long text
    </p>
```

Comment: it will bw better if you add some snippet example... so i added